# Incompatible Shapes with Keras Transpose Convolution

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

```
# Importing the required Keras modules containing model and layers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D,Conv2DTranspose
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

# Creating a Sequential Model and adding the layers
model = Sequential()
#63 kernels - Conv of 3X3
model.add(Conv2D(63, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=input_shape)) 
#Then pooling of 2X2 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Flattening the 2D arrays for fully connected layers
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))  #Combat Overfitting, drop random elements
#Softmax layer must have neurons = range of labels, 0-9 for this case
model.add(Dense(5,activation=tf.nn.softmax))   

#Visualize Network Architecture
plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train, epochs=1)
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I resolve it?

InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 9 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).

I have labels 0,1,2,3,9 . Only 5 labels , which is why in my last layer in inputted an output of 5

```
model.add(Dense(5,activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

However, the system seems to only recognise by the range 0,1,2,3,9 - a range of within 10. How can i make changes to the codes such that it would be be able to output as 5, instead of having the need to change it to 10.

Comment: You `Flatten` which means it isn't a 2D image anymore. You need to either reshape, or not flatten.

Comment: thanks , how about now? after removing the flatten function i get this

Comment: @Tonz what output shape you're expecting from your model?

Comment: @Zabir AI Nazi i am expecting the original shapes of the Mnist images , 28X28, the structure goes like this  , input from mint - conv layer of 64 , 3X3 , pooling layer of 2X2 , dense layer of 1000 neurons , finally transpose convo (decoder) from previous input ( in this case i set it as 64 filters , 3X3, to reverse the conversation layer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the network you're looking for.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D,Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

# Creating a Sequential Model and adding the layers

input_shape = (28,28,1)

model = Sequential()
#63 kernels - Conv of 3X3
model.add(Conv2D(63, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', input_shape=input_shape)) 
#Then pooling of 2X2
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Conv2DTranspose(63, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(1, (3,3), padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
import numpy as np
x_train = np.random.randn(10,28,28,1)
y_train = np.random.randn(10,28,28,1)
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train, epochs=1)
```

1. First of all, in the last Conv layer you must ensure that, the number of filter = number of channels in mnist.
2. If you used MaxPooling2D, you need to apply UpSampling2D to upscale the feature maps to get the original shape.

Always, looking into model.summary helps to get a better idea of the intermediate feature map shape.

```
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 63)        630       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 63)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 14, 14, 63)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DTr (None, 14, 14, 63)        35784     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 1)         568       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2 (None, 28, 28, 1)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 36,982
Trainable params: 36,982
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: AI Nazi , thanks for your kind help! i tried to run the code and got this  : model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train, epochs=1)                                        InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,1] vs. [32,28,28,1]
  [[node Equal (defined at <ipython-input-20-efdf8495a20e>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4570]

Function call stack:
train_function

Comment: updated, your loss function was wrong, it should be binary_crossentropy/mse.

Comment: oic why , in this case , we have a total of 0-9 classes in mint dataset , can i ask a noob question? why are we using binary , when its multi class

Comment: and also noted in this case , we have skipped the dense layer of 1000 neurons , is it possible to include this layer just before the transpose layer? i tried doing so but there is error                                                                              model.add(Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.relu))   thank you very much for ur help!

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the problem, your model suggests an encoder-decoder architecture, in encoder-decoder we try to reproduce the input (slightly differently), it's not classification. It's a pixel level reconstruction, if pixels are normalized 0-1, sigmoid is appropriate, if not then no activation, in such case mse is preferred. Your architecture is not suitable for classification, hence removed the dense layer, you can still keep it but it would require some reshaping.

Comment: thank you for the corrections -                                                                                  Epoch 1/30
44/82 [===============>..............] - ETA: 28s - loss: 0.1122 - accuracy: 0.0391           tried fitting the model , the above says 82 datapoint , in a normal classification , i have a total of 24562 datapoint to be classified , for the auto encoder solution it dropped to 82, is this normal?

Comment: You can also adjust the stride of your convolution instead of using an explicit upsampling layer.

Comment: @Tonz the 82 doesn't denote the datapoint. I guess you're using an older version of keras. Try to upgrade the version.

Comment: thanks Zabir , I have made some changes to the query again , there is another issue i encountered, see changes above . Thank you very much!